# Update not understood

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a p:selectOnelistBox component and a p:commandButton within a p:form component!

Initially the button is disabled, and I want to enable the button when the user selects an item from the list!

I've the following inside the p:selectOneListBox component to set the disabled flag to false using the projectPageBean (ViewScoped) valueChanged method:

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{projectPageBean.valueChanged}" update="@this"/>
```

The p:commandButton component looks like:

```
<p:commandButton id="test"
                 value="View Instrument"
                 rendered="#{projectPageBean.rendered}"
                 disabled="#{projectPageBean.disabled}"
                 action="#{projectPageBean.getPage}"
                 update="@this,:add-instrument-dialog-form:scrolladd"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to work!? What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: you sure about the `p:form` ? cause there is no such thing , use `h:form` , also try to change `update="@this"` so it will update your button (for example update="@form")

Comment: Sorry, of course it is h:form!

Comment: Yes, changing to @form does indeed update the button! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to update your `<p:commandButton` from your `p:selectOneListBox` ajax

So change your `<p:ajax update="@this"....` to `<p:ajax update="@form"` so it will update your button, you also can place your button id or some other id of that button wrapper (instead of the `"@form"`)